# Number of squares formed using p and c

Tags: contest-math, combinations

Points having integral coordinates $(x, y), 0 < x < 9$ and $0 < y < 9$ are joined by straight lines. The number of squares of any size that will form is 
A)385
B)520
C)825
D)1025

The sides need not be parallel to the coordinate axis. The squares with any integer coordinate in the given range must also be counted.

My take on the question-

All squares = (squares with sides parallel to the coordinate axis) + (squares with sides not parallel to the axis)

Squares with sides parallel =  Σr² = ((r)(2r+1)(r+1))/6 = 9.10.19/6 = 15.19 = 285

Squares with sides not parallel = manual counting = 540

All squares = 540 + 285 = 825

Is there any shorter method for doing this calculation?

Comment: Please show your efforts on the question to avoid it being closed or heavily downvoted. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults) to know how to ask a good question on this website. (Please take note that this website does **not** do your homework for you)

Comment: I hope your query got solved now ?

Comment: Yes. It did. I would also request you to continue this for your future posts too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a pattern to be observed. The number of such squares is $\frac{1}{12}n(n+1)^2(n+2)$.

For more information, read [this](https://brilliant.org/discussions/thread/squares-on-a-grid/).

Comment: Thanks for the help !